# How to reset value of dropdown menu and un-display image in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently I am working on a reset button, that sets all the content back how it looked like.

This is how it looks like so far as an example:

```
def reset():
   box1.deselect()
   box2.deselect() #unticks all checkboxes
   self.sendingBTN['state'] = 'disabled' #disables buttons back how I needed them to be
```

Now I am struggling how to set the dropdown value back to default. My dropdown menu values consist of paths of all jpg files inside a specific folder.

I have already assigned it a default value of:

`self.vars.set('All JPGs listed here..') # set the default option`

But, when I choose a value from the drop down menu, default value dissaperars and that's why I am figuring out how to reset it.

Also, I am not too sure how to remove the Image from displaying.

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
self.vars = StringVar()

# Directory
self.directory = "C:/Users/spice/Desktop/allFiles/"
self.choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.directory, "*.jpg"))
self.vars.set('All JPGs listed here..') # set the default option

# Images
def change_dropdown():
    imgpath = self.vars.get()
    img = Image.open(imgpath)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label2.image = photo
    label2.configure(image=photo)
    self.CaptureScreen['state'] = 'normal'




#return path value
self.p = None
def function2(value):
    global p
    self.p = Path(value)
    print(self.p)
#reset values
def reset(): 
    self.Checkbox1.deselect()
    self.Checkbox2.deselect()
    self.Checkbox3.deselect()
    self.Checkbox4.deselect()
    self.Checkbox5.deselect()
    self.Checkbox6.deselect()
    self.Checkbox7.deselect()
    self.Checkbox8.deselect()
    self.Checkbox9.deselect()
    self.Checkbox10.deselect()
    self.Checkbox11.deselect()
    self.Checkbox12.deselect()
    self.CaptureScreen['state'] = 'disabled'
    self.dataSend['state'] = 'disabled'


#widgets
self.msg1 = Label(main, text = "All files here")
self.msg1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
self.popupMenu = OptionMenu(main, self.vars, *choices, command = function2)
self.popupMenu.grid(row=1, column=0)
self.display_label = label2 = Label(main, image=None)
self.display_label.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan = 500)
self.open_button = Button(main, text="Open", command=change_dropdown)
self.open_button.grid(row=3, column=0)
self.resetBtn = Button(main, text = "reset", command = reset)
self.resetBtn.grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = W)
```

this is what I have tried to put into `def reset()`

```
        change_dropdown.delete(label2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resetting your drop-down menu to default value, you can try the following code:

```
def reset(): 
    self.vars.set("All JPGs listed here..")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to remove the image by using this:

```
config(image='')
```

Next, I will try to clear the dropdown content..